# How to add custom columns to Custom Post Type admin screen

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, admin, columns

I have another dumb question, but I can't get one thing :)

I've found this very good article on creating custom post types:

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type/

I'm not sure how Step 4 works.

This guys writes:

```
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "portfolio_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-portfolio_columns", "portfolio_edit_columns");

function portfolio_edit_columns($columns){
  $columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "title" => "Portfolio Title",
    "description" => "Description",
    "year" => "Year Completed",
    "skills" => "Skills",
  );

  return $columns;
}
function portfolio_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;

  switch ($column) {
    case "description":
      the_excerpt();
      break;
    case "year":
      $custom = get_post_custom();
      echo $custom["year_completed"][0];
      break;
    case "skills":
      echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'Skills', '', ', ','');
      break;
  }
}
```

I have two different post types ('books' and 'movies').

And I can't get how to link this code with right one!

I'm sure I'm missing something (most likely in the code), but I didn't see him including "portfolio_edit_columns" anywhere in the code.

I have found this in WP Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column and it seems like

> manage_edit-${post_type}_columns

does the magic, but I've tried both manage_edit-books_columns and manage_edit-movies_columns and nothing! :)

So how to create two separate column layouts for different post types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code from ThinkVitamin is right. I think the problem came from else where in your code.

Actually, the hook `manage_edit-${post_type}_columns` takes an argument `$columns` which is an array of all registered columns. To add a new column, just add a new element to this array, like this:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-film_columns', 'my_columns');
function my_columns($columns) {
    $columns['views'] = 'Views';
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: I know how to add columns, I don't know how to display some of them for custom post type movies and some for custom post type books. And that's what the question is about.

Comment: Oh, I saw you said "I've tried both manage_edit-books_columns and manage_edit-movies_columns and nothing" and I thought you had problem with adding columns. Anyway, the link I provided has a good example with explanation how to show content in columns, you should read it.

Comment: I still don't get that. I'm using two separate filters but it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 4):

It´s even easier than you belive.

You have this two functions on wp:

```
manage_posts_columns (notice the "posts" part)

and

manage_posts_custom_column (again "posts")
```

You have same thing for pages, "manage_page_posts_columns" and "manage_page_posts_custom_column" (notice the "page_posts" part)

So, if you need to add those cols for x post type, you only need to do like this, le´t say your custom post type name is "movie", then:

```
manage_movie_posts_columns()
manage_movie_posts_custom_column()
```

**Notice the "movie_posts" part, that´s why you see something like "manage_{custom_type}_posts_columns" on codex pages.**

For a "books" custom type:

```
manage_books_posts_columns()
manage_books_posts_custom_column()
```

And so on... got it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how the rewrite $arg for your custom post type is.

To get a better view of the output data, just do something like

```
echo '<pre>';   
print_r($custom_post_type_obj);   
echo '</pre>';
```

on the post type object when querying it.